# routes and views

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I am using nodejs with express. On a get-request to the root path I want to route to an index file. If there is a get-request to the path "/game" I want to route to a different source.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render( "index", {locals : { myLocal : "myValue"}} );
});

app.get('/game', function(req, res){
    res.render("/game/index", {locals : { myLocal : "myValue"}} );
});
```

The first "get" works nice but the second sends this exception:

```
500 Error: failed to locate view "/game/index"
at Function.exports.compile (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:15)
at ServerResponse.res._render (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:417:18)
at ServerResponse.res.render (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:318:17)
at exports.game (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\routes\index.js:12:9) at callbacks                  (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
at param (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:11)
at pass (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:253:5)
at Router._dispatch (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:5)
at Object.middleware [as handle] (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:45:10)
at next (D:\Webstorm\myExpress\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\http.js:204:15)
```

This is my folder-structure:

```
views
  |--- game
  |      |---index.jade
  |      |---layout.jade
  |---index.jade
  |---layout.jade
```

UPDATE ########

I checked express itself (file: "\express\lib\view.js", function:"_render") and printed out the local "options.root". The value is: "D:\Webstorm\myExpress/views".. that does not seem to be right. But I still wonder why the root-request works. I changed this line:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

to this:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '\\views');
```

with no success.

Comment: Did you try losing the first slash of your path?

Comment: Yes I did this whith this result: 500 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I am talking about your path in the render function, not app.get.

Comment: That is strange. Have you tried using `game/index.jade` as `game.jade` in your `views` directory to make sure your template file works correctly?

Comment: Ja. I tried differend folder and filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Since I work on a windows machine I have to use "\" instead of "/". I was confused about it because I dont have to care about that in the requests-paths ( app.get("/game",..) ) and not for the root index file. ( res.render("/"); )

The solution is:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '\\views');
```

and

```
res.render('\\game\\index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `locals` keyword from there and its corresponding braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash:

```
res.render("game/index", {locals : { myLocal : "myValue"}} );
```

or:

```
res.render("game\\index", {locals : { myLocal : "myValue"}} );
```

It is trying to find a file at `/game/index`, instead of `/directory/with/your/views/game/index`.